# Trouble making form responsive on mobile

Tags: css, forms, mobile, responsive

I have a form embedded on a SquareSpace site. I would like to make the form responsive on mobile devices. This is what I have tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
  table.infusion-field-container {
   max-width:250px !important;
  }
  }

@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
 button {
   max-width:250px !important;
   position: relative;
    top: 50%;

  }
  infusion-submit {
    text-align: center;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
  tbody.infusion-field-container {
        max-width:250px !important;
  }
}
```

The form is on this page https://www.soulspacehealers.uk/

Should I be using max-width or min-width?

Comment: Add `table-layout: fixed;` to your tables, This is what you get when use tables for layout a mild headache to find the problem

Comment: Thanks Zohir. Would I add that CSS inline within all the table HTML or as some global CSS? Thanks.